# OAuth getRequestToken with custom parameters

Tags: php, oauth

Im trying to use [PHP OAuth library](https://www.php.net/oauth) and specifically the [getRequestToken()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.getrequesttoken.php) method. A problem I've discovered is that I cant add custom parameters to my request. I would like to add the parameter "scope" but I can't find any way to do that. If I try to add the parameter to the URL it seems like all other parameters are failing like so:

```
$oauth->getRequestToken( "http://www.api.com/oauth/request_token?scope=email", "http://www.mypage.com/callback.php" );
```

This is a full example of a working API call but without the needed custom parameter:

```
$oauth = new \OAuth( "consumer_key", "consumer_secret" );
$oauth->setNonce( sha1( \Str::Random( 10 ).time() ) );
$oauth->setTimestamp( time() );

try
{
    $oauth->getRequestToken( "http://www.api.com/oauth/request_token", "http://www.mypage.com/callback.php" );
}
catch ( \OAuthException $e )
{
    exit( $oauth->getLastResponse() );
}
```

So: How do I add custom parameters to a OAuth call with the PHP OAuth library?

Comment: http://www.api.com/oauth/request_token?scope=email  <-- looks like you have added it.

Comment: Yes, but in that case the request fails. It seems like all other paramters are missing if I add one to the URL. I get "oauth_problem=parameter_absent" in the callback and a list of all other paramters which is missing.

Comment: i would check the doucmentaion for the API you are trying to connect to see what they require for parms to be sent.

Comment: I'm the one building the API and OAuthProvider as well :) But I'd like to add the parameter "scope" as a required parameter. The API works well but in my testing against the API with PHPs PECL OAuth extension I can't add custom parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was missing if someone else encounter this problem. The solution is a combination of the methods "fetch" and "setAuthType". The method [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php) allows custom data as a second parameter. This way I could add my "scope" parameter like so:

```
$oauth->fetch( "http://www.api.com/oauth/request_token", array( "scope" => "email" ), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET );
```

This combined with the method [setAuthType()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.setauthtype.php) made it possible. setAuthType() need a constant named OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_*. For this to work I added the constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI which appends the OAuth parameters to the request URI.